# Problems with a Static IP address

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

I am trying to set a static IP address on my RPI, which is working, but I have no internet access. It is connected directly to my router via a cat5 cable. I was using my WIFI, but it seemed to lose connection within 5 minutes. I have had a lot of problems with my RT5370. I don't mind using Cat5 due to the location, and less issues.

My windows PC shows the following info:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.0.1
DHCP Server 192.168.0.1
DNS Servers 75.114.81.1
            75.114.81.2
```

My /etc/network/interfaces on the pi shows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 19.68.0.1
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameserver 75.114.81.1

auto wlan0
#allow-hotplug wlan0
#wireless-power off
#iface wlan0 inet static
#address 192.168.0.222
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off

#auto wlan1
#allow-hotplug wlan1
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I can ping between devices, but no access to google, saying "Unable to display this website. No address associated with hostname"

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"What am I doing incorrectly?" I assume apart from setting a static IP address  and the obvious typing errors in your file.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)